# Silverlight RIA Services related entities loading on server but not client

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, ria

I have an extenal class library with my entities in it.  In the Silverlight hosting project I have a domain service class exposing those entites to the silverlight app.  When I query for an entity with the include method, it loads the related entities on the server, but they are not being passed to the client.  Here is the entity - I ended up adding a metadata class after searching for a solution on stackoverflow, but that didn't change anything:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(ProjectManager.ProjectManagerMetadata))]
public partial class ProjectManager
{
    public ProjectManager()
    {
        this.Jobs = new HashSet<Job>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ProjectManagerKey { get; set; }

    public string TenantID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public string PIN { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    internal sealed class ProjectManagerMetadata
    {
        private ProjectManagerMetadata()
        {
        }

        [Include]
        [Association("ProjectManagerJob", "ProjectManagerKey", "JobKey")]
        public ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is the query - I tried "ToList()" thinking it might help. It didn't

```
    public IQueryable<ProjectManager> GetProjectManagers()
    {
        List<ProjectManager> proj = (from p in trs.ProjectManagers.Include("Jobs") where p.TenantID == tenantID select p).ToList();
        return proj.AsQueryable();
    }
```

In the debugger on the server side, one ProjectManager and his seven related jobs are loaded, but in the silverlight app (in the debugger) there are no related jobs. What am I missing?

EDIT: Here is the client code:

```
    public void InitialDataLoad()
    {
       busyHelper.Busy("Loading...");
       trx.Load(trx.GetProjectManagersQuery(), this.InitialLoadCompleted, null);
    }

    private void InitialLoadCompleted(LoadOperation loadOp)
    {
        busyHelper.BusyDone();
        if (!loadOp.HasError)
        {
            foreach (ProjectManager manager in trx.ProjectManagers)
            {
                foreach (Job job in manager.Jobs)
                {
                 // no jobs returned 
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorWindow.CreateNew(loadOp.Error);
            loadOp.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, the jobs entityset of the datacontext (trx in the code) is being populated, but the jobs property of the individual projectmanagers is not.  In other words:

```cs
trx.ProjectManagers.Count = 4
trx.Jobs.Count = 9
trx.ProjectManagers[2].Jobs.Count = 0 //(Should be 9)
trx.Jobs[0].ProjectManagers.Count = 0 //(Should be 1)
```

Comment: In this situation I find you are often encountering a serialization error which is hidden from you unless you disable Just My Code debugging.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make a difference.  No new errors

Comment: What do you call "in the silverlight app"? Could you post the code to see how you get this in the SL app? Do not forget this is an asynch call. And have you a single datasource?

Comment: You enumerate by ToList(). Ok. Try change return type IQueryable to EntityCollection.

Comment: What code do you use on the client-side ? Actually your code seems fine on the server-side to load the data. But you need to pass the data from the server to the client.

Comment: Client code added in the edit

Comment: I discovered that the context's Jobs entityset was being populated, but the projectmangers.Jobs property is still not.  See Update.